C# Exit code of another process is always zero on Unix
EDIT #2: Seems this isn't possible, but I'll leave this question in case someone else tries this and runs into this issue.

I have two processes that run independently, A exits with some code other than 0, B waits for A to exit and prints the exit code. B does not start process A, it just receives its pid as an argument.
// process A
Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit...");
Console.ReadLine();
Environment.Exit(100);

// process B
int pid = int.Parse(args[0]);
using var proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
// Save SafeHandle, otherwise it throws
// InvalidOperationException: Process was not started by this object
_ = proc.SafeHandle;
proc.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(proc.ExitCode); // always prints 0

Is there a way for B to actually get the exit code? If I run echo $? in the terminal where I start process A, I do get 100, but I'm not sure how I can get the exit code from a process that hasn't started the process I'm monitoring.
Edit: The _ = proc.SafeHandle line was added because of this answer.

"Otherwise it throws when we try to get exit code" - That's a hint you're doing something wrong...

The documentation for Process.SafeHandle says it can only be used if the calling program also created the process. As you're using Process.GetProcessById(Int32) then you can't use SafeHandle at all.

Generally only the process that created the new process can retrieve the exit code.

Using a discard with SafeHandle isn't the same thing as try/catch - so your _ = proc.SafeHandle; doesn't suppress any exceptions (just compiler warnings). If you do get an actual exception, then please share all details of that exception, including the full stack-trace, HResult (even on Linux), InnerException, etc.

@Dai The exception is InvalidOperationException: Process was not started by this object. I added that line after I found this answer.

@Cristi The requested information should be [edit]ed into the question.
